# How to extend package types?

Tags: typescript, electron

Trying to extend Electron [app](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app).

```js
import { app } from "electron"

app.foo = "bar" // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'App'.ts(2339)
```

Above works if I use `//@ts-ignore`.

Trying to setup a `.d.ts` override but what I came up with doesn’t work (just getting started with overrides).

### electron.d.ts

```js
import { App as ElectronApp } from "electron"

declare module Electron {
  export interface App extends ElectronApp {
    inspect: boolean
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) is what I was looking for.

### electron.d.ts

```js
declare namespace Electron {
  export interface App {
    inspect: boolean
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import `app` under a private name and then typecast it internally to be whatever you like.

```
import { app as _app } from "electron"

interface MyCustomProperties {
  foo: string;
}

const app = _app as (typeof _app & MyCustomProperties);
app.foo = "bar";
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out… can one achieve this using a `.d.ts` override?

Comment: You're quite welcome. You probably can do it with `.d.ts`. I'll let someone who's more familiar with Electron specifically answer the specifics on that.